# How much will Starship SN8 weigh on liftoff?

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship

Apparently SN8 recently underwent a 'Cryo' pressure test and to do that the press stated that 1000 tonnes of liquid Nitrogen was used! Is that really true? That got me thinking: just how much does this Starship weigh on liftoff? I have tried searching the internet with little and confusing results, does anybody here know how much it will weigh for its 50,000' test flight?

Comment: Nitpicking: you should ask what it's *mass* will be, since shortly after liftoff its *weight* will be huge as a result of the launch acceleration.

Comment: Absolutly Carl, however I was really trying to get a sense of the task that those engines will face. I know the figure will not be exact as fuelling takes place up until just before launch. I'm trying to visulise it in everyday items, like how many 40 ton trucks it would be. I dare not think about the booster too!

Comment: Do the Gross Weight and Propellant Mass values at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Starship  suffice?

Comment: Or the tables at  http://spacelaunchreport.com/bfr.html